# Why children component with redux-form doesn't re-render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Parent Component send data but children don't re-render, only when press a key on a input.

SMART
I send userValues form state, if i put a console.log(this.props.state.userValues) in render(), component smart render when redux get new properties.

```
import React, { Component, RefObject } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import WebappHeader from '../../containers/WebappHeader/WebappHeader';
import BlueSection from '../../containers/BlueSection/BlueSection';
import Title from '../../components/Title/Title';

import { getBase64, isString, userData } from '../../helpers';

import * as styles from './MyAccount.css';
import * as actions from './../../actions/accounts';
import { updateAccountInformation, getAccountInformation } from '../../services/AccountService';
import UserProfile from '../../components/UserProfile/UserProfile';

interface State {
    tabActiveClass: string;
    extensions: string;
    file_64: string;
    unsavedChanges: boolean;
}

interface Props { state: any, actions: any }

class MyAccount extends Component <Props, State> {
    private fileInput: RefObject <HTMLInputElement>;
    private avatarImage: RefObject <HTMLImageElement>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { ...this.props.state }
        this.avatarImage = React.createRef();
        this.fileInput = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            getAccountInformation().then(result => {
                result.user
                    ? this.props.actions.userAccountLoad(result.user)
                    : null
            });
        }, 1000)
        // setea la primera tab como la que esta activa
        this.setState({ tabActiveClass: document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].classList[2] });
    }

    handleSubmit = (userData: any): void => {
        // console.log(userData)
        updateAccountInformation(userData)
            .then((result: any) => {
                !result.error
                    ? this.props.actions.userAccountUpdate(result)
                    : this.props.actions.userAccountError()
            })
    }

    private uploadAvatar(files: any): void {
        if (files.length > 0){
            let file = files[0], extensions_allowed = this.state.extensions.split(',');
            let extension = `.${file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()}`;
            if(extensions_allowed.indexOf(extension) === -1){
                alert(`This extension is not allowed. Use: ${this.state.extensions}`);
                this.fileInput.current!.value = '';
            } else {
                getBase64(file, (result: any) => {
                    this.setState({file_64: result, unsavedChanges: true});
                    this.avatarImage.current!.src = result;
                    console.log(result); // nueva img, ejecutar disparador
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private changeTab(e: any, name: string): void {
        let i: number;
        const future_tab: any = document.getElementById(name);
        const tabcontent: any = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        const tablinks: any = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(` ${this.state.tabActiveClass}`, '');
        }
        future_tab.style.display = 'flex';
        e.currentTarget.classList.add(this.state.tabActiveClass);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <BlueSection styleName="section">
                <WebappHeader />
                <div styleName="tabs-headers">
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <Title text="Account Information" />
                        <ul styleName="list">
                            <li styleName="item active" className="tablinks" onClick={(e: any) => this.changeTab(e, 'profile')}>
                                Profile
                            </li>
                            <li styleName="item" className="tablinks" onClick={(e: any) => this.changeTab(e, 'activity')}>
                                Activity
                            </li>
                            <li styleName="item" className="tablinks" onClick={(e: any) => this.changeTab(e, 'plan')}>
                                Plan & Billing
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div styleName="tabs-body">
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        <ul styleName="list">
                            <li styleName="item" id="profile" className="tabcontent" style={{'display':'flex'}}>
                                <UserProfile 
                                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                    userValues={this.props.state.values}
                                    // avatarImage={this.avatarImage}
                                    // uploadAvatar={this.uploadAvatar}
                                    // fileInput={this.fileInput}
                                />
                            </li>
                            <li styleName="item" id="activity" className="tabcontent">

                            </li>
                            <li styleName="item" id="plan" className="tabcontent">

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BlueSection>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({ state: state.account });
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) });

const ComponentWithCSS = CSSModules(MyAccount, styles, { allowMultiple: true });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentWithCSS);
```

CHILDREN

I receive userValues form smart component, if i put a console.log(this.props.userValues) in render(), component doesn't render when get new properties.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import { InjectedFormProps, reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Heading from '../Heading/Heading';
import Button from '../Button/Button';
import Input from '../Input/Input';

import * as styles from './UserProfile.css';

interface Props {
  userValues: any,
  avatarImage: any,
  uploadAvatar: any,
  fileInput: any,
  handleSubmit: any,
}

const inputField = ({ input, label, type, meta, disabled, field_value }: any) => (
  <div>
    <Input
      {...input}
      labelText={label}
      styleName="input"
      type={type ? type : "text"}
      disabled={disabled ? disabled : false}
      placeholder={field_value ? field_value : ''}
    />
    {/* fix mejorar mensajes css */}
    {
      meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>
    }
  </div>
)
const isRequired = (value: any) => (
  value ? undefined : 'Field Required'
)

class UserProfile extends Component<Props & InjectedFormProps<{}, Props>> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() { this.props.initialize({ name: this.props.userValues.name }) }
  public render() {
    console.log(this.props.userValues)
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.forceUpdate() // temp (bad) fix
    // }, 2000)
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div styleName="right-info">
          <Heading text="Your data" styleName="heading" />
          <form id="UserProfile" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} method="POST" styleName="form">
            <fieldset styleName="fieldset">
              <Field
                name="name"
                label="Name"
                validate={isRequired}
                placeholder={this.props.userValues.name}
                component={inputField} />
              <br />
              <Input
                labelText="Email"
                styleName="input"
                type="email"
                disabled={true}
                placeholder={this.props.userValues.email} />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset styleName="fieldset">
              <Field
                name="phone_number"
                label="Phone Number"
                validate={isRequired}
                component={inputField} />
              <br />
              <Field
                name="company"
                label="Company"
                validate={isRequired}
                component={inputField} />
            </fieldset>
          </form>
          <Heading text="Notifications" styleName="heading" />
          <form styleName="notification-form">
            <label styleName="label">
              I wish to recieve newsletters, promotions and news from BMS
              <input type="checkbox" name="notifications" />
            </label>
            <p styleName="disclaimer">
              <span styleName="bold">Basic information on Data Protection:</span> BMS collects your data too improve our services and, if given consent, will keep you updated on news and promotions of BMS projects.  +Info Privacy Policy
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div styleName="cta-wrapper">
          <Button
            onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}
            text="SAVE CHANGES"
            filled={true}
          // disabled={!this.props.state.unsavedChanges} 
          />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const UserProfileWithCSS = CSSModules(UserProfile, styles, { allowMultiple: true });
export default connect()(reduxForm<{}, Props>({ form: 'UserProfile' })(UserProfileWithCSS));
```

REDUCER 
I think it's okay

```
import { USER_ACCOUNT_UPDATE, USER_ACCOUNT_LOAD, USER_ACCOUNT_ERROR } from './../actions/types';
import { userData } from '../helpers';

const engine = require('store/src//store-engine');
const storages = require('store/storages/sessionStorage');
const store = engine.createStore(storages);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    tabActiveClass: '',
    extensions: '.jpeg,.jpg,.gif,.png',
    file_64: '',
    unsavedChanges: false,
    values: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone_number: '',
        company: '',
        notifications: false
    },
};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_ACCOUNT_LOAD: {
            let newState = state;

            newState.values.name = action.payload.profile.first_name;
            newState.values.email = action.payload.email;
            newState.values.phone_number = action.payload.profile.phone_number;
            newState.values.company = action.payload.profile.company;

            return { ...newState };
        }
        case USER_ACCOUNT_UPDATE: {
            let newState = state;
            let storage = store.get('user_data');

            storage.profile.first_name = action.payload.data.name;
            storage.profile.company = action.payload.data.company;
            storage.profile.phone_number = action.payload.data.phone_number;

            newState.values.name = action.payload.data.name;
            newState.values.phone_number = action.payload.data.phone_number;
            newState.values.company = action.payload.data.company;

            store.set('user_data', storage);

            return { ...newState };
        }
        case USER_ACCOUNT_ERROR:
            return { ...state };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know if it can help, but can you try let newState = { ...state }; and return newState only instead of return { ...newState } as current to see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correctly creating a new `state` object in your account reducer, which is sufficient to signal to your parent component that the mapped props have changed.  However, in your reducer, you're always carrying forward the same `values` object.

```
case USER_ACCOUNT_LOAD: {
    let newState = state;

    newState.values.name = action.payload.profile.first_name;
    newState.values.email = action.payload.email;
    newState.values.phone_number = action.payload.profile.phone_number;
    newState.values.company = action.payload.profile.company;

    return { ...newState };
}
```

This isn't a problem when it comes to triggering renders in your parent component, since `state.account` has an updated reference after each action.  However:

```
<UserProfile 
    ...
    userValues={this.props.state.values}
    ...
/>
```

`UserProfile` is specifically being passed the `values` object, and will thus be doing its shallow reference checks for incoming props on the `values` object, not the state object.  Since `values` always refers to the same object according to your reducers, `UserProfile` will not re-render when `props.userValues` changes.  If you're going to be passing a property of one of your props to a child component, you need to ensure that it ALSO passes the shallow reference check:

```
case USER_ACCOUNT_LOAD: {
    let newState = { ...state };

    newState.values = {
        ...state.values, // Copy all properties from old state
        name: action.payload.profile.first_name, // Replace individual properties with new values.
        email: action.payload.email,
        phone_number = action.payload.profile.phone_number,
        company = action.payload.profile.company
    };

    return newState;
}
```

And the same idea for `USER_ACCOUNT_UPDATE`.

This is why its much safer to *always* treat objects and arrays as immutable in your reducers.  Your reducers are currently fine for signalling Redux of changed state, but you lose the guarantee when/if you start prop-drilling as you're doing with `UserProfile`.

Comment: Thanks so much bro.. you are the papus of the papus